# Экранирование в rm

Tags: shell, bash

Нечаянно создал файл с именем --exclude. Теперь не могу его удалить

не работает:

```
rm --excluderm "--exclude"rm "*exclude"rm *exclude
```

Помогите кто чем сможет)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй

```
rm \\-\\-exclude
```

или

```
./--exclude
```

Comment: Экранирование пробовал, не работало.А вот про ./ забыл, не догадался. Сработало, спасибо!

Comment: Именно   rm ./filenameэто универсальный способ.А если не уверены в чем-то, то добавляйте флаг `-i` это переводит `rm` в режим подтверждения удаления файла. Например    [avp@nas tmp]$ rm -i a*    rm: удалить обычный файл «a1»? y    rm: удалить обычный файл «a2»? n    rm: удалить обычный файл «a3»? y    [avp@nas tmp]$ ls a*    a2    [avp@nas tmp]$

Answer (score 1):

С liveCD зайдите, там всё можно!

Но можно и `sudo rm -F *exclude`! Не делайте только `sudo rm -rF /` ! Это очень жестокая шутка.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/files | grep exclude | xargs rm
```